# Dynamic javascript vs window.onload

Tags: javascript, pageload

I have a classic ASP page which contains a JavaScript script loaded dynamically like this:

```
sub MySub()

   if(true) then
      Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'> " & VbCrLf & _
                            "window.onload = function(){ " & VbCrLf & _
                                "fAfchrPopup(); "& VbCrLf & _
                             "} "& VbCrLf & _
                            "function fAfchrPopup() " & VbCrLf & _
                             "{ " & VbCrLf & _
                                " document.getElementByID("divModal").style.display = 'block'" & VbCrLf & _
                                " document.getElementByID("divShade").style.display = 'block'" & VbCrLf & _
                            " }" & VbCrLf & _
                        "</script>")
   end if


End Sub


<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
    <div id='divShade'></div>
    <div id='divModal'>
        <div id='divModalEntet'>
        </div>
        <iframe id='frmContn' src='<URL>' frameborder='0'> 
        </iframe> 
    </div>  
</body>
```

The first time the page loads, the modal div takes too long to show.
After refreshing the page, the element shows up quickly.
I can't put the script directly in the html, because there is a validation that must be done on server side (vb).

Comment: The time it takes for the dialog to be shows is the time it take for the server to execute the said validation and to send back the JavaScript. You might want to optimize your validation code, otherwise it's all about the server response time. The reason the element is shown faster after a refresh is because the browser caches most of the content of the page.

Comment: I would really, *really* recommend against writing JavaScript like this. There is almost certainly a better way to do what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Ok. Is there any alternative for window.onload? Response.Write? I'm open to use a better way.

Comment: `window.onload` is fine. I'm suggesting you don't generate javascript server side like this.

Comment: Since the function you are writing does not contain any sensitive information, why not add it in a JavaScript file that it probably already within your page? the validation could be done in AJAX and the function would be called only if the desired result is returned from the AJAX call. Or add some kind of URL parameter that the JavaScript checks to call the function or not. There's many possible alternatives, and some might not be suitable for what you are specifically trying to do but these are suggestions.

Comment: Hum... If I use a server side variable to show my div like: 
if ("<%myVar%>" )
{
     showPopup();
}
I don't know...
I can't use AJAX.